Not being redirected to "/onboarding", even after the logic is correct
I am making a project using Next js version 14.1.1, in that after the user is authenticated, they are to be redirected to localhost:3000/onboarding, but they are not being redirected, even if I type it manually, it redirects me to home page, what is the issue, not able to figure out
here is the code of app/[locale]/onboarding/page.tsx
import { OnboardingFormProvider } from "@/context/OnboardingForm";
import { checkIfUserCompletedOnboarding } from "@/lib/checkIfUserCompletedOnboarding";


const Onboarding = async () => {
  const session = await  checkIfUserCompletedOnboarding("/onboarding");
  console.log(session);

  return (
    <OnboardingFormProvider session={session}>
      <p>
        Onboarding
      </p>
    </OnboardingFormProvider>
  )

};
export default Onboarding;


here is the code of checkIfUserCompletedOnboarding
import { redirect } from "next-intl/server";
import { getAuthSession } from "./auth";

export const checkIfUserCompletedOnboarding = async (currentPath: string) => {
  const session = await getAuthSession();
  if (!session) redirect("/");
  
  if (session.user.completedOnboarding && currentPath === "/onboarding")
    redirect("/dashboard");
  
  if (!session.user.completedOnboarding && currentPath !== "/onboarding") {
    redirect("/onboarding?error=not-completed-onboarding");
  }

  return session;
};


after consoling it is returning what am I expecting, but it is not redirecting
here is the github link of my project - https://github.com/HemantRaj-2005/super-productive
I thought it was the problem of the version, earlier I was working with Next15, but I got a solution of downgrading the version, but even after that I am not able to figure it out

You might need to navigate to localhost:3000/en/onboarding, with the [locale] value. Either way, add more logs to see exactly what line is throwing the user to the homepage.

I've tried to run your code and tried login using email & password, it works.
No issues with the control flows in your code. Try to delete all installed packages and reinstall; import useRouter from next/navigation instead of next-intl/client.
And remember to include [locale] in the url if you want to access manually by tying url on your browser. E.g. Should be localhost:3000/en/onboarding or localhost:3000/te/onboarding instead of localhost:3000/onboarding

Can you tell me, after sign in, have you been redirected to /onboarding ?? And I tried once again everything, that you told to do, but I am facing the same issue.

Yes. You also can try set a mock data for account in components/auth/SignInCardContent.tsx. Or you can deploy current code to vercel, I'll help in case

Sir I am currently I am facing errors in deployment, I can make you contributor and give access of my repo

It seems getAuthSession returned an incorrect result. Try adding NEXTAUTH_SECRET=any_thing_you_want in your env
